# GCC ARM multiplication optimization

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, arm, compiler-optimization

I was reading about ALU design and [Booth's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth%27s_multiplication_algorithm), which is used to optimize multiplication in binary. That got me curious about how compilers like gcc would optimize multiplication, for processors where multiplication is not as fast as bit shifting such as ARM 32bit. Here is the ASM obtained when trying to multiply a variable by `0xaaa` (which is the worst case of Booth's algorithm):

```
    mov     r2, r3      // r3 is an arbitrary variable
    lsl     r2, r2, #1
    add     r2, r2, r3
    lsl     r3, r2, #3
    sub     r3, r3, r2
    lsl     r2, r3, #6
    add     r3, r3, r2
    lsl     r3, r3, #1
```

I can't seem to grasp any pattern or rule that had made the following output. I thought of looking at the source code of gcc but I have no idea where to look in. Can someone shed some light on what the algorithm is, and how does it generalize to any multiplier?

Comment: Did a compiler really emit that with separate `mov` and `shift` instructions?  That seems terrible.  ARM can copy-and-shift even in Thumb mode, can't it?  gcc uses the `mul` instruction when tuning for most modern ARM cores, but for "generic" tuning with ARM (not thumb), it uses 3 `add` instructions with barrel-shifted inputs, in one register.  https://godbolt.org/z/QfUtY9  Then a final `lsl`.  There's no `mov`.

Comment: Take a look here https://godbolt.org/z/zE86JS. C++ seems to produce different output than C.

Comment: No, you just didn't enable optimization.  I'm surprised how bad the `-O0` output is, but anyway https://godbolt.org/z/2dDmU8 shows that C and C++ (`gcc -xc++ -O3`) produce the same output.  They're both use `rsb` (reverse-subtract) as one of the steps.

Answer (score 3):

The assembly you posted isn't a generalized multiplier - the compiler has executed some algorithm offline and hard-coded the constants and arithmetic operations needed for a fixed `f(X) = X * 0xaaa` computation.

```
mov     r2, r3      // r2 = X, r3 = X
lsl     r2, r2, #1  // r2 = 2 * X
add     r2, r2, r3  // r2 = 2X + X = 3X
lsl     r3, r2, #3  // r3 = 8 * 3X = 24X
sub     r3, r3, r2  // r3 = 24X - 3X = 21X
lsl     r2, r3, #6  // r2 = 64 * 21X = 1344X
add     r3, r3, r2  // r3 = 21X + 1344X = 1365X
lsl     r3, r3, #1  // r3 = 2 * 1365 = 2730X = 0xAAA * X
```

In this scenario the compiler doesn't need to use a general purpose multiplication algorithm like Booth's; it knows the value it's trying to aim for, so it just predetermines the best way to generate the constant scaling by `0xAAA` using shifts, adds, and subtracts.

The general problem is the "Single Constant Multiplication" problem - there are papers online (optimal solutions for arbitrary numbers of bits is a "hard" problem, so there are lots of reasearch papers).

Comment: Following the Booth's algorithm, shouldn't the third instruction be a `sub` instead?  I can see how in the last two step, the compiler did an optimization by doing`10101000000 + 10101 << 1 = 101010101010` but the ones before seems incomprehensible.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not using Booths, but having started to write the reply I'm actually not sure what algorithm it is using - the one I thought it was using I can't get to work in a Python mockup ...

Comment: FYI, as it might be interesting, and includes and online generator: https://www.spiral.net/hardware/multless.html

Answer (score 1):

elementary multiplication, not everything you find is going to use some algorithm that someone put their name on.

decimal

33 * 12

```
  33
* 12
=====
  66  ((33*2)<<0)
+33   ((33*1)<<1)
========
```

base 2 has the feature that the second operand can either contain zeros or ones

0b110 * 0b101

```
    110
*   101
=========   
    110     ((110*1)<<0)
   000      ((110*0)<<1)
+ 110       ((110*1)<<2)
===========
```

the non-zero bits are what matters.  So multiplying times five is

x * 5 = (x*4) + (x*1) = (x<<2) + x = ((x+x)<<1) + x = ((x<<1)<<1) + x

x * 10 is just that shifted left one more time.
x * 10 = (x*8) + (x*2) = ( (x+x)<<1) + x) << 1

and so on you can game it however you like to optimize for the target architecture.

0xAAA = (0x5<<9) + (0x5<<5) + (0x5<<1) or (1<<11) + (1<<9) + (1<<7) + (1<<5) + (1<<3) + (1<<1)

various ways to optimize from there.

Comment: The question was asking specifically about the behaviour of the compiler in this scenario (with a fixed operand) which isn't really a general purpose multiplier, nor "elementary" multiplication. Optimal solutions to the design of a constant multiplier block (i.e. with minimal numbers of adders) is an NP-hard problem.